# PrestaShop 1.7 configuration, Permission denied to appParameters.php

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have a problem installing `prestashop` 1.7.6.0
the installation itself through docker-compose passes correctly, when it configures such instances, at the third step it receives an error regarding the lack of file permissions.

I am not sure how to perform this installation without the need to manually grant permissions for this file, i.e.

```
docker exec -it ID_CONTAINER / bin / bash
chmod 667 /var/www/html/var/cache/prod/appParameters.php
```

Please help.

following is in my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - /var/lib1/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ps
      MYSQL_USER: ps
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ps

  prestashop:
    #build: .
    image: prestashop/prestashop-git:7
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      PS_INSTALL_AUTO: 1
      PS_ERASE_DB: 0
      DB_SERVER: db
      DB_USER: ps
      DB_PASSWD: ps
      DB_NAME: ps
      PS_DEV_MODE: 1
      PS_DOMAIN: localhost:8080
      PS_FOLDER_ADMIN: admin123
      PS_FOLDER_INSTALL: install123
    volumes:
      - /var/www/html
```

Installed and start is ok but next step is configuration,

```
db_1          | Version: '5.7.28'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
prestashop_1  | [Sat Oct 26 08:35:29.065962 2019] [:error] [pid 17] [client 172.19.0.1:57442] PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/html/var/cache/prod/appParameters.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/config/bootstrap.php on line 87
prestashop_1  | [Sat Oct 26 08:35:29.066041 2019] [:error] [pid 17] [client 172.19.0.1:57442] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/var/cache/prod/appParameters.php' (include_path='/var/www/html/vendor/pear/pear_exception:/var/www/html/vendor/pear/console_getopt:/var/www/html/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src:/var/www/html/vendor/pear/archive_tar:.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /var/www/html/config/bootstrap.php on line 87
```